# How to create C++ typeclass with multiple traits?

Tags: c++, inheritance, traits, typeclass, composition

Traits are mechanism to mix-in behaviors without using multiple-inheritance.

In C++ Traits are called `typeclasses`.

Is it possible to use multiple traits (combine them) in C++ code?

I tried to use C++ projects like https://github.com/TartanLlama/typeclasses , but can`t find way to combine multiple Traits.

I also tried code like:

```
template <typename ... Ts> class(typeclass) trait_combo : public Ts... {};
```

```
class(typeclass) printable {
    void print();
};

class(typeclass) drawable {
    void draw();
};

struct foo {
    void print() { std::cout << "foo"; }
    void draw() { std::cout << "foo"; }
};

struct bar {
    void print() { std::cout << "bar"; }
    void draw() { std::cout << "bar"; }
};
```

```
std::vector<printable> v;
v.push_back(foo{});
v.push_back(bar{});
v[0].print();
v[1].print();

std::vector<drawable> v1;
v1.push_back(foo{});
v1.push_back(bar{});
v1[0].print();
v1[1].print();
```

Expected to use multiple traits similar to:

```
std::vector<trait_combo<printable, drawable>> v2;
v2.push_back(bar{});
v2.push_back(foo{});
```

Do you know any C++ patterns or projects that allow creation of C++ typeclasses with multiple traits?

Comment: *"In C++ Traits are called `typeclasses`."* Is this an actual standard C++ thing I don't know about, or it some sort of extension/library/build tool? To me, traits in C++ means type traits like those in `<type_traits>`.

Comment: This is not standard C++ it is an experimental implementation of a proposed feature, which is in the very early phases of standardisation.

Comment: Have you tried `template <typename ... Ts> class(typeclass) trait_combo : public Ts... {};`?

Comment: Notice that anyway, you should have `struct foo {
    void print() { std::cout << "foo"; } void draw() { std::cout << "foo"; }
};` You cannot split definition of `foo`/`bar` as you do.